# Linux version and jdk version is not compatible

Tags: java, spring-boot

the same code ,when I use maven to package codes on the `Linux 6.0.10`,the final jar can not run successful,but I do this on `Linux 8` ,it works well.
The `jdk version is 1.8`

Exception as following:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor':
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean
>   definition at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1287)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:179)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE] at
>   cn.j.lithium.LithiumApplication.main(LithiumApplication.java:16)
>   [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131] at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131] at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131] at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>   [lithium-0.0.1-test.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>   [lithium-0.0.1-test.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>   [lithium-0.0.1-test.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>   [lithium-0.0.1-test.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean
>   definition at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:407)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:68)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE

Comment: What makes you think they are not compatible? Does the same runs on different configuration? Which this configuration it is? Also, what do you refer as "Linux 6"?

Comment: the same codes,package it as executable jar on different linux version os .There are two jar ,one packaged on low linux version(it can not running),one packaged on high linux vesion(it running successfully)

Answer (score 1):

Ok. It's really hard to understand what's going on with the stacktrace you posted (likely you didn't post it whole) - so here is my guess:

Linux is a ([kernel](https://www.kernel.org/)) and there is no such version of it, so I assume you mean one many distros, possibly Debian (first link in google for `Linux 6.0.10`). You can check this with `cat /etc/*-release` in console.

[Distrowatch website](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=Debian) says that `Debian 6.x` it is bundled with is OpenJDK 1.6 - which is way too old for Spring version you are using.

Feel free to use the latter website to look for your distro if it's not Debian.

Comment: yes,I used Debina 6,I installed jdk is 1.8,Are they not compatible,when I compiled the java files?

Comment: Well seems not to be the issue... Are you sure that proper JRE for running your app is used, if you have them both installed?

Comment: I used the 'java' command of jdk/bin to execute jar ,Is it right? I already add the java home to the PATH variable

Comment: Try `java -version` to check

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_131/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
java -version

Comment: Execute command `java -version` in the folder you run your app, it shoud print out the version used

Comment: /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java -jar xxx.jar,I used this command to execute the jar,but it is not running and throw a exception above that i descirbed it

Comment: I see, so you explicitely define the executable. Something else might be the cause then. Please update the question saying this is Debian and maybe add some other details, so others may answer. Also, check if you have posted the whole stacktrace (last lines are usually more important).

Comment: I packaged jar on Debian 8 ,coped the jar to the Debian 6,it is running successful.it is so strange